# Getting List values in ActionResult Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am learning mvc 4. Im new to mvc and i had implement ajax call for passing parameters and
I have one List shown in below:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<Reportdata> ReportTransaction(string dfromdate, string dtodate, int stype)
{
      List<Reportdata> reportdataobject = new List<Reportdata>();
      System.Globalization.CultureInfo format = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
      var linq = (from db in Invmsobject.sp_procReports(DateTime.ParseExact(dfromdate, "MM/dd/yyyy", format), DateTime.ParseExact(dtodate, "MM/dd/yyyy", format), ((stype == 1) ? "In" : "Out").ToString())
                 select new Reportdata
                 {
                            ITransactionDate=db.TransactionDate.ToString(),
                            IProductName=db.ProductName,
                            ITransactionType=db.TransactionType,
                            IQty=db.Qty,
                            IUserName=db.UserName

                 }).ToList();
     return linq;
```

}

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Report()
        {              
            return View();
        }
```

I dont know how to assign this list values to this Report Controller. 
    I can assign by using this List name[ReportTransaction] but this List having Parameters that why i'm getting struck on this... I had use ajax call for passing parameters in this list.. This List working fine but i could not able to get this List datas to Controller. can anyone help me how to handle this kind of situations..

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify: "dont know how to assign this list values to this Report Controller"  I assume since it is decorated with [HttpPost] your ReportTransaction method is a controller action itself.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't what you are asking, please clarify what you are trying to do, as it is unclear.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Report()
    {              
        return View(ReportTransaction(...));
    }
```

View:

```
@model List<Reportdata>

<h2>Details</h2>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <div>@item.IProductName</div>
}
```